# Blender 3.1 EEVEE: why is part of this image, visible in render mode, not visible in render?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I just completed the ["Endless Flight Loop with Geometry Nodes"](https://youtu.be/F2NcNJQZFqw) YouTube tutorial.  When I run the looping animation in the 3D Viewport, in either *Material Preview* or *Rendered* Viewport shading mode, the results look fine:

[image: rendered viewport shading mode]

but when I render the image, the plane renders properly, but the "topo" lines almost completely disappear:

[image: Actual render]

I've disabled the compositor pass with no change and explored a lot of camera, EEVEE, and shader settings, but nothing seems to change the result.

The shader is fairly simple, although it brings in two attributes from the Geometry Nodes:

[image: Shader snapshot]

Shader settings seem OK:

[image: shader settings snapshot]

The Geometry Nodes screenshot is, of course, unreadable:

[image: Geometry Nodes]

Any hint as to what's going wrong in the actual render would be greatly appreciated.

Note:  This requires 3.1 geometry nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Airplane" collection is hidden in the Viewport, but not in the Render ; so the big mesh in this collection blocks the view of the mountain.

Either Disable it for render (in the Outliner, Camera icon), or Exclude it from the view layer (Checkbox icon)

Comment: Nailed it.  I can't believe I missed something that simple.  Thank you very much.